# Which algorithm is more often used in recommendation system?

Tags: machine-learning, logistic, svm, data-mining

I have a data set with 100,000 instances and about 40 features. Each instance is a customer and each feature is a property of the customer. The first column is binary 0/1 which indices whether the customer click the ads. The task is fitting the data with models or one model and predicting if a new customer will click the ads or not.

I want to start with only one kind of model to do this but don't know which model is suitable. I can think svm (with libsvm), logistic regression. I don't think matrix factorization methods can help because the columns are features of the customer, not items.

Comment: Can you provider more informations about the items in this recommendation system? Do you have only one Ads or multiples?

Comment: @imanis_tn Just only one ads. And I agree with Adrien Renaud. May be I need a classifier, not a recommender system.

Answer (score 1):

Given the nature of the data shown in your question, it seems that **your are looking for a classifier algorithm and not a recommender system**.

A recommender system would answer the question: "What particular ads to show to this particular user".
Your question is really different: "Will a new customer click the ads or not".

To build a recommender system, you need to record interactions between users and item**s**. In your case, it seems that you have only one item. Intuitively it seems clear that you can't build a recommender with one item.

With only one item, you are good to use classifier algorithm. 
Choosing a model for a binary classification problem is a very broad subject. 
You mentioned two very good examples, **svm** and **logistic regression**. I would add a third one that is **very often used**: **boosted decision trees** like in adaboost or xgboost.

Comment: ...beyond classification some kind of probability estimate of the customers clicking the add or not may be useful to optimize the gains of a given strategy. That should be attainable by all recommended models.